# What does whoopty-skippy-do mean?

Tags: meaning

What does *whoopty-skippy-do* mean?

> Because if that's your plan then *whoopty-skippy-do,* sign me up!" Tito appeared, leaning over the hood. “My ears are burning. I hope you're not talking about me,"...
>
> Source: [*Turbo* Junior Novelization,](http://goo.gl/AfJeyU) Simon & Schuster

Comment: It's a pragmatic marker subclass extreme enthusiasm marker subclass child's register. Compare Zip-a-Dee-Doo-Dah. As Joffysloffy says, though, words are often used ironically, even sarcastically.

Comment: This one is a latter-day variant on [*"Whoopie-doo"*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bUFYAAAAMAAJ&q=%22whoopie+doo%22&dq=%22whoopie+doo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cGyVVMmnM5TXat75gJgH&redir_esc=y), for which the earliest written instance I can find is that one from 1969. All  such alternatives to *"Hooray! [for you]"* are usually used sarcastically.

Comment: Kinda like "whoopty-do" only different.  It's common to insert various nonsense terms between "whoopty" and "do", as emphasis.  Usually doing so implies that the "enthusiasm" is sarcastic (though this is often the case with "whoopty-do" itself, even without the addition).

Answer (score 6):

As far as I have seen, it is used as a sarcastic cheer. It is used as ‘excellent!’, ‘brilliant!’, ‘genius!’ sarcastically.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It *is* something that's said (US) after learning one has received a three cent a week raise: "*Well, whoopty-skippy-do!*"

Comment: +1 - though it should be noted that it is a sort of over-the-top sarcasm. The connotation is more of "that is completely obvious" or "you are an idiot" in addition to sarcastically mentioning how bad the idea/plan/thing is.

Comment: It's not used to mean "excellent" or the like it's used to mean "big freakin' deal" in a really sarcastic way.  In other words "Who cares? That's not worth even mentioning. Why are you even wasting my time telling me about it?"

Comment: @Jim I think that fits less well in the asker's quote.

Comment: Joffy- yes you are right. For some reason I didn't see the quote.  Of course I'd never use that phase the way that author did- that's more of a "Woo Hoo!" In my mind.

Comment: @Jim Fair enough! After I read your comment your definition does sound more familiar.

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a one-off extension of *whoop*, meaning 'hooray' or something similar, and usually used ironically. The OED thinks *whoop-de-do* [the only form I have ever encountered] means "a fuss, bustle or commotion: a 'to-do' (*U.S. colloq.*)", but its first citation, *The Red Badge of Courage*, is " ‘Whoop-a-dadee,’ said a man, ‘here we are! Everybody fightin' ", which fits better with your example than their own definition.

Comment: In fairness, it should be noted that the first citation is in square brackets, which [“indicates a quotation is relevant to the development of a sense but not directly illustrative of it”](http://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-symbols-and-other-conventions/), so it’s not like they just ignored the discrepancy in meaning between that citation and the meaning they give. Still odd, though, that the present meaning of _whoop-de-doo_, which in my experience is by far the commonest, is not mentioned at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's a sarcastic expression of enthusiasm (ie. indicating no enthusiasm whatsoever).

"Whoopty-do" by itself is occasionally used as a genuine expression of enthusiasm, but is usually used sarcastically.  "Whooptyd-*<intensifier>*-do" (typically "whoopty-fucking-do") is invariably sarcastic.

Answer (score 0):

It should ordinarily mean "Big Fat Hairy Deal". (Note tmesis for emphasis and satirical irony).

Other similar expressions:

A) Tell the Salvos (A reference to the Salvation Army, who "care", as I don't).

B) Yeah, I read about it in "Big Whoop" magazine. – Panucci.

However, because of the "sign me up", it is an exuberant, boisterous expression of celebration as one might expect from a slack-jawed yokel.

Because of this, the full context is important, it may yet be a "not want" parodied expression.

Such as "Oooh, please, can we?" delivered together with a rolled up magazine to the face. Often used on sitcoms.

In the case of the referenced work, the "set up" is in the description of the option, (downplaying the upside as a downside) and the delivery of a "want very badly" acceptance, as the "run down mall" etc. is actually an attractive proposition.

Also common filler material for sitcoms.